News: Adobe is being sued buy the US government regarding anti-trust subscription practices
https://www.theverge.com/2024/6/17/24180196/adobe-us-ftc-doj-sues-subscriptions-cancel

The Justice Department alleges that Adobe hid early cancellation fees and trapped consumers in pricey subscriptions.

...roughly 20 years late.. but finally.
